# Error when calling glfwCreateWindow() on OS X after updating to Sierra

Tags: opengl

I have got a weird bug that I cannot figure out. The Apple forums were not too helpful.
I updated my MacBookPro (Retina, early 2015) to the newest OS X Sierra. My code ran fine before, now when I call `glfwCreateWindow(mWidth, mHeight, mTitle, nullptr, nullptr);`, I get following error:

```
> ERROR: Setting <private> as the first responder for window<private>,but it is in a different window ((null))! This would
> eventually crash when the view is freed. The first responder will be
> set to nil.
```

I have got no idea, why my program does not work and yes, I have set the glfw to be forward compatible.

P.S. computer info:

- MacBook Pro (Retina 13 inch, early 2015)
- CPU: 2.7 GHz Intel core i5
- GPU: Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

Comment: Are you able to include your code in the question? I recommend removing most of the code until you stop getting the error message, so you can then provide just enough code to cause the error message. This will help narrow down the source of the problem and is likely to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: The problem is not my Code, it used to work fine with OS X El Capitan. The Error I get has something todo within the underlaying window management of OS X Sierra. I have contacted Apple already and they are working on resolving the issue

Comment: If there's some aspect of your code that worked with the old version but doesn't work with the new version, then we would need to see your code to narrow down what needs to change to work with the new version. If the problem is a bug in closed source software provided by a company, then that would make this question off topic here as we have no way of fixing the problem. If you think there's a chance it is the first, providing a [minimal working example](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/126/should-we-require-minimal-working-examples-mwes) will allow us to investigate.

Comment: I have the same issue with a PDF view when using full screen. To what I found else on the net this looks like a Sierra bug :-(